# Isn't every Endofunctor an identity Functor?

Tags: category-theory

I mean Endofunctor maps category $A$ to category $A$ - so all of it's objects, and morphisms must remain the same. Isn't this an identity Functor?

For example, if I have a category $A$ of integers with an ordering on them:

> $O = \{1,2,3,4\}$
>   $M(x,y) = \{(x,y) |  x,y \in O, x \leq y)\}$

any Endofunctor I try to think of ends up being an identity Functor...

What I am thinking wrong here? Thanks.

*EDIT*: As per suggestion, let me try mapping all objects, via and endofunctor $F$ to $1$ and all morphisms to $1 \leq 1$.

$$F_{O}: O_{A} \to O_{A}, F_M: M_{A} \to M_{A}$$

then $F_{O}(1) = 1, F(2) = 1, ...$ and $F_{M}( M(1,2) ) = M(1,1) $

so now either:

1. Nothing is changed and $A$ remains the same (endofunctor having only "mapped" things around)
2. Or the new $A$ is now missing all objects except for $1$ and all morphisms except for $1\leq 1$.

If it's the former (1), what is the point of this functor in the first place, if it does  not "do" anything...

Comment: In your example, try mapping every object to $1$ and every morphism to $1\leq 1$.

Comment: But doesn't that change the set of "objects"? Now we only have one object! I thought category $A$ is only equal to another category $A$ if all objects and morphisms are the same?

Comment: I imagine you meant to write "$F_O(2)=1$" rather than "$F(2)=2$"?

Comment: Regarding your point 2, there isn't a "new $A$". The functor $F_O$ you have defined maps $A$ to itself: for each object $a$ of $A$, $F_O(a)$ is an object of $A$, and if $f:a\to b$ is a morphism of $A$ then $F_O(f):F_O(a)\to F_O(b)$ is a morphism of $A$. It *is* true that the "image" of this functor is the subcategory of $A$ that has only the object $1$, but that's okay.

Comment: By analogy, an *endofunction* of a *set* $X$ is just a function $f:X\to X$. So, for example, the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ is an endofunction of $\mathbb{R}$. The image of this function doesn't contain, for example, $-1$, but it is still a function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. And it is not the identity function $id(x)=x$ either.

Comment: @Brad Thanks, yes I meant $1$, fixed!

Comment: @Brad I think I understand what you mean! (I think you should put it in an answer.) I am just finding it hard to keep track of where the category is used as a concrete entity (i.e. defined exactly by it's set of objects, morphisms etc) and where it is used as a "domain" or "range" for things (I guess that would only be in functors).

Comment: Functors do not need to be injective or surjective, and images need not be a whole codomain.

Comment: It's true identity functor is a special case of endofunctor, therefore every endofunctor is not always identify functor in that scale, however, when the scale of perspective is up, every endofunctor becomes identify functor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to give extra constraints to the definition of "endofunctor". In reality it is just a functor from/to the same category. It does not have to be an identity.In particular, note that an endofunctor does not have to be full or faithful or injective/surjective on objects.  Consider - as a parallel - a set $A$ and a function $f: A \to A $. Is $f$ necessarily the identity function? Of course not! It could be a permutation on set A or a constant function, or...

Answer (score 8):

No. The objects and morphisms don't have to remain the same.
An endofunctor is just a functor of the form $A\to A$, for a category $A$.

For example, $X\mapsto \{0,1\}\times X\ $  is an endofunctor on $Set$.

In your example also any *constant* mapping will give an endofunctor, also ($1\mapsto 1,\ 2\mapsto 1,\ 3\mapsto 4,\ 4\mapsto 4$) works...

Comment: I'm sure the OP would appreciate an example of a non-identity endofunctor on some category.

Comment: But... that changes the set of objects in the category, wouldn't that change the category $A$ to something like $A'$?

Comment: @drozzy: Why would it? The other objects are still there, even if the functor isn't mapping anything to them.

Comment: @camccann Perhaps I don't know what $X\mapsto \{0,1\}\times X$ means... could you explain?

Comment: @drozzy: I was talking about the constant mapping example, but the same applies to both. Perhaps a more straightforward example would be an ordering on the natural numbers, and a functor that maps each number to its successor?

Comment: So... you are saying simple reordering of objects... and then changing all morphisms to point to correct objects again. Wouldn't that still be an identity (kind of)? I mean what's the difference between ordering and a successor - aren't they the same?

Answer (score 1):

Take the category of "data structures", it's objects are basic types like numbers $\mathbb N$, booleans $\mathbb B$, pairs of objects $(a,b)$ and lists of objects $[a]$.

An example of a functor is the list functor: if we have a morphism like $\text{odd} : \mathbb N \longrightarrow \mathbb B$ then the list functor gives us $[\text{odd}] : [\mathbb N] \longrightarrow [\mathbb B]$ (which computes `[F,T,F,T]` from `[0,1,2,3]`)

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason, every "endomap" of sets $f: X \longrightarrow X$ would always be an identity, wouldn't it?

So, for instance, the only function $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ would be the identity function, $f(x) = x$. And things like $f(x) = x^2, \sin x , e^x \dots$ and the like strange, inexplicable phenomena.  :-)